# Swift draw semicircle, not filled

Tags: swift, draw

I guess I am doing something horribly wrong, but I need to present you my idea. I want to draw something like a semicircle about 180 degrees, which has three different colours. But I don't want it to be filled out, I just want to have it the circle itself.
I am using this code:

```
func addCirc(colour: UIColor, perc: CGFloat) {
    let center = CGPoint(x: 150, y:150)
    let radius = min(200, 200) / 2
    let startAngle = 0 / 100 * CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2 - CGFloat(Double.pi)
    let endAngle = perc / 100 * CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2 - CGFloat(Double.pi)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: center)
    path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    colour.setStroke()
    path.close()
    path.lineWidth = 20
    path.stroke()
}

let leftColour = UIColor.red
let middleColour = UIColor.yellow
let rightColour = UIColor.green
addCirc(colour: rightColour, perc: 50)
addCirc(colour: middleColour, perc: 30)
addCirc(colour: leftColour, perc: 10)
```

The result looks like the following:
[image]

So I just want to have the circle itself and delete the bottom line and the diagonal ones. I guess it's wrong to use addArc in this situation.
Does anybody know an alternative to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I think the call to `path.close` is making all those straight lines appear. If you just want one single arc and nothing else, why not try the initializer `init(arcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)`?

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 70), radius: 50, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 10
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

You can create something like this:

[image]

If you want different parts of the arc to be different colors, you probably want to remember the angle where the previous part of the arc ends (i.e. store the angle in a variable). You doesn't seem to be doing this at the moment.

Here's what I've been able to come up with:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    var lastArcAngle = -CGFloat.pi
    func addArc(color: UIColor, percentage: CGFloat) {
        let fullCircle = CGFloat.pi * 2
        let arcAngle = fullCircle * percentage
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 70), radius: 50, startAngle: lastArcAngle, endAngle: lastArcAngle + arcAngle, clockwise: true)
        color.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 10
        path.stroke()
        lastArcAngle += arcAngle
    }
    addArc(color: .red, percentage: 1.0 / 6.0)
    addArc(color: .green, percentage: 1.0 / 6.0)
    addArc(color: .blue, percentage: 1.0 / 6.0)
}
```

Comment: You are right, thank you! pathClose isn't solving it totally because it also draws the way from the centre to the beginning of the circle. Your alternative initialiser works, thanks! Concerning the remembering of the previous arc: Thats true, I just did not do this in my example above.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand See the edit for my attempt at creating a colourful semicircle

Comment: I just need to ask one more think, it makes me crazy: How can I centre this the best way on an own UIView? So I want to substitute (100,70). x should be self.bounds.midX, but I am struggling to find the correct y.

Comment: I might be just confused about bounds, frame, self and so on.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand Depending on which centre you mean, either `(bounds.midX, bounds.midY)` or `(bounds.midX, bounds.midY + radius / 2)`

Comment: It's the last one. Thank you! Have a great day.